# C++ Vector + Array, vector have inexistent data

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm developing a program and I have this piece of code:

```
struct Point{
    int x, y, map;
}; // Portal Position

struct HPortal{
    Point startMap, targetMap;
    int MapTitle, PortalType;
}; // Portal Struct

std::vector<HPortal*> Portals[20001]; //Portal Array, total 20001 maps
```

But it throws me errors in "random" accions.

I saw with VS debugger that the arrays have a lot of data.  I didn't initialize them (for testing purposes I'm only using one portal, in the first map).

I searched a little bit and I think the var is too big, and the program doesn't respect the space of the array and overwrites it.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Where do the `HPortal` objects get created and destroyed? (Alternatively… are you sure you don't want to use a `vector<shared_ptr<HPortal>>` or a `boost::ptr<vector<HPortal>>` or something else that helps manage the lifetime of the portals?)

Comment: Also, are you sure you want this giant array on the stack (or in a static or global, or wherever it is)? For example, could you be using one or more of the vectors (e.g., because you pass them around by reference somewhere) after the stack frame has exited? Because that's exactly the kind of thing that throws "random" errors—it may take quite some time before 160K worth of stack gets overwritten, so the crash may come much later than the actual problem…

Comment: Finally, "the var is too big, and the program doesn't respect the space of the array" is not possible on any modern system (that kind of thing _could_ happen with some old DOS memory models and similar, but I assume you're dealing with 32 bits or more). So, the problem is in some code you haven't shown us. Most likely it's one of the things I mentioned above, but there are all kinds of other possibilities, including completely unrelated code that stomps the stack or heap, so there's no way we can debug it further without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), or at least more of your code.

Comment: @abarnert did you perhaps mean `boost::ptr_vector<HPortal>` in the first comment?

Comment: @Kos: Yes, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of 20001 std::vectors on the stack. You are aware of this? Are you sure you don't want

```
std::vector<HPortal*> Portals(20001); // holding x HPortal POINTERS
```

or

```
std::vector<HPortal> Portals(20001);; // holding x HPortals
```

In the first case you have an array of `std::vector<HPortal*>` on the stack, which is a pretty limited piece of ram, allthough a tiny test sample revealed that it takes only ~ 240kb ram on the stack. But, it might be still a problem, depending on the rest of the stack. If you would use `std::vector< std::vector<HPortal*> > Portals(20001);` instead you would create the same amount of elements on the heap (which is capable of holding much more elements).

To check if some parts of your code do arbitrary things and overwrite other parts of your program / memory can not be checked by the code you provided.

Comment: Yes, every space in array are map, and the vector contains the Portals of the map (ex: Portals[map][portal_num]->PortalType;)

Comment: May editing the HPortal struct and adding the map in the portal will increase the "stability"?

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @ErniCA: the stability issue can't be solved by the pieces you provided. if you use pointers to structs you must be sure what you are doing and the pointers should point to valid structs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this removing the [20001]; Now i look every var if the Portal->startMap.map it's the same of player. And the "corrupt" memory i seen my VS done it with all vectors arrays, i need print the debugs for get the information :I

Comment: Well, yeah, replacing an array with a single shared value will solve any problems with that array. But presumably you had that array for a reason, and getting rid of it will bring you a whole new set of (more obvious, but less solvable) problems, so I'm not sure how this is an answer.